# Use of static class in C#

Tags: c#, class, static

I'm developing an appliaction that has 2 forms and I ran into a problem. When I create a new instance of a class in Form2, then close Form2, I lose the instance values. So, I've solved this using static class, is this the correct approach?

The class name is `Matriz_de_registracion` and I have a function within it that's called "solver" that assigns values to the class properties ("Double MR0" is one of the variables as an example)

here's the code in Form2 (see I don't use the "new" statement otherwise once I close form2 I loose the instance values..

```
    private void btn_iniciar_registro_de_puntos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Matriz_de_Registracion.solver(_pois);
    }
```

Then I can reference, in Form1, one of the properties of the Class by just doing this:

```
    Matriz_de_Registracion.MR0
```

Now, is this correct approach or static classes are used for something else? I just wan to reference the values of the MR0 variable across all my forms without having to pass the instances through forms every time I open/close forms.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right approach.  You should copy the values from the form object after it has closed but before you get rid of it.

The problem with using static data anything other than extremely sparingly is that you will find it makes the application much harder to work on as it gets larger - for example, you wouldn't be able to open two instances of the form at the same time, as they'd tread on each other's data.

Comment: So, once I close Form2, where I copy the instance values so that are available to be used in Form1?

Comment: You should copy them to wherever you need them.  You should aim not to be writing all your application logic in form classes anyway, so think about what the data from form1 is being used for and put that in a class of its own.

Comment: so, what code would you use to make that happen, like for instance, once the user clicks on "Done" in a button in Form2, call a function in Form1 that creates an instance of the class and clones the instance from Form2?